# How do I calculate the average value of a pixel's surrounding pixels?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, noise-reduction

I am trying to create a 5x5 mean filter to remove some salt and pepper noise from an image. I read the image into a numpy array. And tried making some changes to calculate the average value of a pixel's neighbors. The result I got is quite bad and I can't seem to figure out why there are gaps in my image result.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy

image1 = 'noisy.jpg'
save1 = 'filtered.jpg'

def average(path, name):
    temp=Image.open(path)
    image_array = numpy.array(temp)
    new_image = []
    for i in range(0, len(image_array)):
        new_image.append([])
    n = 0
    average_sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(image_array)):
        for j in range(0, len(image_array[i])):
            for k in range(-2, 3):
                for l in range(-2, 3):
                    if (len(image_array) > (i + k) >= 0) and (len(image_array[i]) > (j + l) >= 0):
                        average_sum += image_array[i+k][j+l]
                        n += 1

            new_image[i].append(int(round(average_sum/n)))
            average_sum = 0
            n = 0

    x = Image.fromarray(numpy.array(new_image), 'L')
    x.save(name)
    print("done")

average(image1, save1)
```

---------------------Input image-----------------

[image: Input Image]

---------------------Output image-----------------

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a list for the new image, just make a copy of the original image (or create an array with the same size as of the original image) and change its value with the new averaged pixel values. Like this

```
def average(path, name):
    temp=Image.open(path)
    image_array = numpy.array(temp)
    new_image = image_array.copy()
    n = 0
    average_sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(image_array)):
        for j in range(0, len(image_array[i])):
            for k in range(-2, 3):
                for l in range(-2, 3):
                    if (len(image_array) > (i + k) >= 0) and (len(image_array[i]) > (j + l) >= 0):
                        average_sum += image_array[i+k][j+l]
                        n += 1

            new_image[i][j] = (int(round(average_sum/n)))
            average_sum = 0
            n = 0

    x = Image.fromarray(numpy.array(new_image), 'L')
    x.save(name)
    print("done")
```

This gave me the following output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Extremely slow boxing and unboxing of numpy data (translation to/from python variables and native memory), all those loops with per-pixel reads are **death** in numpy and an abuse of numpy. Your code is *extremely* slow. Numpy is NOT meant as a storage container for random manual math like that. Numpy is meant for internal math using its native C++ functions. As for the example above: Just use OpenCV with `cv.blur()` for super high performance in 1 line of code, instead. And OpenCV has many other filters too, like gaussian blur and median blur and custom kernels etc.

Comment: The question was not on how to implement the algorithm faster or what other libraries can be used. The code had an error and I fixed it (Please read the question). If you are a beginner and you are trying to implement an algorithm, it is okay to come up with a brute force algorithm first and improve the efficiency later.

Answer (score 8):

**I just want to warn anyone else who finds this page. Basically, nobody should ever do `somenumpyarray[y,x]` to directly access pixel values one by one. Every time you type something like that, Numpy has to create 4 new Python objects (the `tuple` object containing RGB values, and the three individual `int` objects for each R/G/B value). That's because in Python, *everything* is an object (even numbers are objects), which means that data can't be "just read directly from Numpy". Actual Python *objects* have to be created instead, and the Numpy data (such as numbers) are *copied* into those objects, *every* time you try to read something from Numpy into Python.**

**That's 4 Python object creations per pixel you try to read from the array. For a 1080p image if you ONLY read each pixel ONCE that's 8 294 400 objects. But the code above checks a 5x5 (25 pixels) matrix around each pixel, so that's 207 360 000 object creations! Insane!**

This object creation is known as boxing (taking native Numpy data and packing/boxing it in a Python object data structure). As well as unboxing (taking Python data, extracting the actual value it contains (such as a number) and packing it into the native Numpy array). Reading / writing values in a Numpy array from Python always involves boxing and unboxing, which is why it's *extremely* slow and you should *always* use native Numpy methods for operating on your data instead. Numpy is NOT a general-purpose "array" for us to treat like any random-access Python List. Numpy is meant for vector / matrix operations using its own built-in functions! In fact, you should never even do `for X in some_ndarray` because iterating invokes the same slow-ass boxing process (every `X` item in such a loop is extracted from Numpy and boxed).

Anyway... what you are trying to implement is a 5x5 "box blur", meaning the average of all nearby pixels within a square 5x5 radius.

You should therefore use a native C++ library which performs it all in pure, clean RAM, without involving Python at all. One such library is OpenCV, which accepts a ndarray (your image pixels), and internally reads directly from the RAM owned by the ndarray, and operates directly on each pixel natively.

Here's the code:

```py
import cv2

path = "noisy.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(path)
img = cv2.blur(img, (5,5)) # This is now your box-blurred image.
```

Benchmarks in a 1920x1080 image:

- Your original code (which abuses the Numpy array to death and creates over 200 million new Python objects): **87.80000 seconds** (and that isn't even counting all the RAM abuse that's going on with the creation of over 200 million objects)
- Using OpenCV instead: **0.02992 seconds** (2935x faster)

Never, ever access Numpy array elements directly. It's not meant for that.

Good luck to any future readers.

---

**Edit: By the way, to answer the original question... to remove salt and pepper noise, you should use *median* filters instead of box blurs.**

**Input:**

[image: input]

**5x5 Box Blur (aka Mean/Average Blur):**

`img = cv2.blur(img, (5,5))`

[image: blur]

**3x3 Median Blur:**

`img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 3)`

[image: median]